# Why when trying to use JQuery on a previously initialized html element variable it returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I read on the JQuery docs ( https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-elements-when-i-already-have-a-dom-element/ ) that you could use a previously initialized element by writing the variable name like you do with selectors:

```
$(element)
```

but whenever i try to do so from a function that i call at the press of a button it returns 'undefined'.

This is an example code i did to test this out in a more controlled environment:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" onclick="jquery(this)">JQuery</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-info" onclick="normaljs(this)">normalJs</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-danger" onclick="basicTest()">basicTest</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-info" id="empty">dynamicTest</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function jquery(caller){
        var element = $(caller).parent();
        alert("Tag name: " + element.tagName);
    }

    function normaljs(caller){
        var element = caller.parentElement;
        alert("Tag name: "+ element.tagName);
    }

    function basicTest(){
        alert("This is a basic test");
    }

    $("#empty").click(function(){
        alert("Tag name: " + $(this).tagName);
        alert("Tag name: " + this.tagName);
    });
</script>
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: `element` is a jQuery object, not a DOM element. `tagName` is a DOM property.

Comment: @Barmar you're right. Can't believe i didn't realized this before. I'm going to pick Mr Geek's answer just because of simplicity but, for the record, it was this comment what made me realize of my mistake. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By `$(caller)`, you just "converted" the DOM element into a jQuery object, therefore, DOM properties and methods won't work in the normal way on it anymore, but if you want to get the tagName using jQuery, then `prop()` would do :

```
function jquery(caller){
    var element = $(caller).parent();
    alert("Tag name: " + element.prop("tagName"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(caller).parent()` returns a jQuery object, but `tagName` is a DOM property, not a jQuery property (jQuery makes very little use of data properties, almost everything is a function). To get the DOM elements contained in a jQuery object, you can use the `get()` function or an array index,.

```js
function jquery(caller) {
  var element = $(caller).parent()[0];
  alert("Tag name: " + element.tagName);
}

function normaljs(caller) {
  var element = caller.parentElement;
  alert("Tag name: " + element.tagName);
}

function basicTest() {
  alert("This is a basic test");
}

$("#empty").click(function() {
  alert("Tag name: " + $(this).get(0).tagName);
  alert("Tag name: " + this.tagName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" onclick="jquery(this)">JQuery</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <button class="btn btn-block btn-info" onclick="normaljs(this)">normalJs</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <button class="btn btn-block btn-danger" onclick="basicTest()">basicTest</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <button class="btn btn-block btn-info" id="empty">dynamicTest</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```